# how to use Interface in adapter class and activity together

Tags: android

How can I update item count in action bar  when the move button in one item (in the `RecyclerView`) is pressed?

My `WishlistActivity` class

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_wishlist);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setTitle("Wishlist");
        toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        wishlistRecycler = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.wishlist_recycler);
        GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this,2,GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);
        wishlistRecycler.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        wishlistRecycler.addItemDecoration(new Space(2,20,true,0));
        adapter = new wishlistAdapter(itemsWish,getApplicationContext(),cartCounter);
        wishlistRecycler.setAdapter(adapter);

        wish_count = dbHelper.getWishCount();
        emptyLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.emptyWishLayout);
        wishLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.wishLayout);
        contShopp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.continueShope);

        cartCounter = new MoveWishlistToCart() {
            @Override
            public void setCounter(int count) {
                Toast.makeText(WishlistActivity.this, "Called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("Log","cartCounter: "+count);
            }
        };
```

My wishlistAdapter class

```
public wishlistAdapter(List<WishlistItems> wishItems, Context context, MoveWishlistToCart cartCounter) {
        this.wishItems = wishItems;
        this.context = context;
        this.cartCounter = cartCounter;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public myViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View rootView;
        rootView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.wish_list,null,false);

        return new myViewHolder(rootView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull myViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        WishlistItems wishlistItems = wishItems.get(position);
        dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);

        wish_sku = wishlistItems.getWishItemSku();
        price = wishlistItems.getWishItemPrice();
        sCount = dbHelper.getCountTotal();

        holder.textBrandName.setText(wishlistItems.getWishItemBrandName());
        holder.textPrice.setText("₹"+wishlistItems.getWishItemPrice());

        String imageUrl = wishItems.get(position).getWishImage();
        Picasso.with(context).load("http://www.app.ssmkanmanam.com/public/images/"+imageUrl).into(holder.mImageview);

        holder.mRemove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Toast.makeText(activity, "Hii", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                removeFromWishlistDb(position);
                wishItems.remove(position);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        holder.textMoveToBag.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                removeFromWishlistDb(position);
                wishItems.remove(position);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                moveToCartDb();

                cartCounter.setCounter(1);


            }
        });
    }
```

My interface class

```
public interface MoveWishlistToCart {
    public void setCounter(int count);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because initially you passed a null `MoveWishlistToCart` to your adapter and then after you initialise it. move the code:

```
cartCounter = new MoveWishlistToCart() {
        @Override
        public void setCounter(int count) {
            Toast.makeText(WishlistActivity.this, "Called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("Log","cartCounter: "+count);
        }
    };
```

above this line:

```
adapter = new wishlistAdapter(itemsWish,getApplicationContext(),cartCounter);
```